# Access all cells in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hi I am tying to iterate through all the cells of my tableview but My tableview variable only let's me access the visible cells. so is there a way to declare the tableview without using the dequeuereusableCellWithIdentifier? or is there a way to iterate through all the cells?

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you want to iterate through the cells?  You may need a different approach - see my answer below

Comment: to get the values of all the text fields I use it to update all the values of a list of elements

Comment: You could try `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, or you could implement a protocol/delegate to update the values as the fields are edited.

Comment: this only let's me access the visible ones

Comment: Ah yes so you should implement a protocol/delegate system to send you the updated information as the fields are edited. This is more efficient than iterating through all the cells as well (as my answer states you should not be iterating through them).

Comment: is there a function for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117556/discussion-between-bradkratky-and-pudm).

Answer (score 0):

To efficiently display a table, cells are used and reused depending on which ones are visible onscreen. In fact, this is what `dequeuereusableCellWithIdentifier` is suggesting - you specify different types of cells so they can be recycled later, as new ones are displayed and the components of offscreen ones are available for reuse.

You should define what needs to be changed or retrieve cells using table view `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

**You Are Already Accessing All The Cells In The TableView.**

**Note:** *I lied, two or more cells may be kept for quick reuse as well by tableView, but are not shown immediately.*

At a time, a tableView only shows limited amount to cells to maintain performance and memory usage. So, for this purpose *dequeuereusableCellWithIdentifier()* method is utilised to let iOS handle the reuse of cells when necessary.

This way, no matter how large the dataSource, from 100,1000 to 1M, for the tableView, it will show the data in its cell smoothly and without any hiccups. That is why, you have limited cells visible and only those are the total cell used and reused by the tableView again and again.

By this definition, the total cell in use are the total *visibleCells*. So, when you are accessing the *visibleCells*, you are already accessing all the cells tableView has in use.

If you want to access all the *data* used by the cell, then please access the *dataSource* of tableView, not the *visibleCells* only.

Kind Regards,
Suman Adhikari